# How to makes div with a paragraph button and other elements inside it in HTML/JS

Tags: javascript, html, element

I have a button that creates a div, that but is easy (`const smth = document.createElemnt(div);`), but the only problem is it is just a blank div. I would like there to be a div with a paragraph and button in it. How do I do that? This is in HTML and JS.

I have tried to do:

```
(document.CreateElement(“p”);
document.CreateElement(“button”))
```

Separately but that isn’t on the div.

Comment: [`.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

Comment: You seem to have some typos in your question, `document.CreateElement()` should be `document.createElement()`, but this is probably just a transcription error, since you’ve used it correctly elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are well
If I understand what you mean
You want to create a div and add it to that element
In JavaScript, you must first create the same div, then use appendChild to add other elements such as p and button.

```js
const divMain = document.querySelector('#main-container')
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        const p = document.createElement('p');
        // p.classList = .....
        // p.textContent = .......
        div.appendChild(p);
        divMain.append(div);
        console.log(divMain)
```

```html
<div id="main-container"></div>
```

**Now to create the button, do exactly the same thing we did to create the p tag**

Answer (score 0):

You need to `append` elements

```js
let counter = 0;

document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (event.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement) {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    const button = document.createElement('button');
    const p = document.createElement('p');
    
    button.textContent = 'Add';
    p.textContent = `${++counter} element created`;

    div.classList.add('new');
    div.append(button, p);
    
    this.append(div);
  }
});
```

```css
.new {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.new p {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Add</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

> here is answer with jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mybtn").click(function(){
  var myhtml=`
  <p>hello world</p>
  <button>hello!</button>
  `;
    $("#mydata").html(myhtml);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="mybtn">
click me!
</button>

<div id="mydata" style="background-color: lightblue">

</div>
```

> if you don't want to use jquery than go for jquery to javascript
> converters like [this](https://properprogramming.com/tools/jquery-to-javascript-converter/)

Comment: JQuery is clearly not being used in the code in the question, nor is it tagged in the question. So while you’re free to offer a jQuery-based answer I’d argue it’s of no meaningful use to the OP. Certainly not if they have to then transpile the code back to native JavaScript.